# Track Skip Event?

Tags: spotify

Is it possible using the SPotify Apps api to observe events that the user may input? Specificlly I would like to capture when a users skips a track in a playlist, so that I can prune the playlist of songs that get skipped repeatedly.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this documentation [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/) it seems that you can do that implementing an EventListener to listen for different actions on the tracks. I believe there is an event called `change` that could be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From my experimentation, this is indicated by the `e.data.duration` value when listening to `change` on `models.player` [[docs](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-player.html)]

https://github.com/matelich/album-radio/blob/master/js/albumradio.js#L383